# Use of quite and too

Tags: grammar

I'm pretty sure the sentence "I'm quite an ambitious man" is standard English, but I wonder if the adverb 'too' can be used the same way.
To put it another way, I'd like to know which of the following sentences are correct:

(1) I'm a too ambitious man

(2) I'm too ambitious a man

(3) I'm too an ambitious man (where too means very, not also)

Thanks in advance for any contributions

Comment: I am too ambitious. I am an overly ambitious man. We are not supposed to just edit/correct like that but sometimes, it's just too easy.

Comment: Colloquially, "I'm too ambitious" would be used (if anything). (2) is highfalutin; perhaps "I'm over-ambitious" falls somewhere in between. (3) is ungrammatical. I'll disagree with Colin and say that (1) sounds non-standard.

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=too+ambitious+a+man%2Ca+too+ambitious+man%2Ctoo+honest+a+man%2C+a+too+honest+man&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctoo%20ambitious%20a%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoo%20honest%20a%20man%3B%2Cc0) and [these](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=too+hard+a+task%2Ca+too+hard+task&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctoo%20hard%20a%20task%3B%2Cc0) seem to support my assessments.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: maybe. GloWbE has 5386 instances of "too [adj] a" against 567 of "a too [adj]".

Comment: @ColinFine Have you read [some of them](https://www.english-corpora.org/glowbe/)?  Perhaps _most_ of them! 'Whereas, you do not need a too big bags with you.' / 'your growth in a too big ocean-like companies where individual growth will be very less.' / 'is a too big of a word for people to admit association.' / 'If a too big to fail banks is too big to exist' / 'the promise of order brough by the Empire come at a too big a price'. Strange corpus. I'll stick with 'non-standard'.

Answer (score 1):

First, *too* does not mean *very*. It means *excessively*. It is sometimes interchangeable with *very*, but it has a connotation of disapproval.

As for your examples, 3. is ungrammatical.

Your 1. and 2. are both grammatical: 1. is colloquial, and 2. rather literary. Some people would use one of these exclusively; some would say 1., but write 2. in a formal context